# Why Wpf cut my button when i put auto size?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

why my button edited with templates is cut on the right side when I try to put the size in automatic ?, if I put the fixed sizes this does not happen.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vhJM.jpg

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="botonProducto" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Grid Margin="20">
            <Ellipse x:Name="outerCircle" Width="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Height="AUTO" Fill="Black"/>
            <Ellipse x:Name="inCircle" Width="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Height="AUTO" Margin="5">
                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                </Ellipse.Fill>
            </Ellipse>
        </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>                    
                <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX=".9" ScaleY=".9"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value=".5,.5"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

C# Code

```
 private void creaBotones()
    {
        int column = 0;
        int row = 0;
        foreach (Producto producto in listaProducto)
        {
            if (column == 4)
            {
                row++;
                column = 0;
            }

            var template = (ControlTemplate)Application.Current.FindResource("botonProducto");

            Button boton = new Button();
            boton.Tag = "/Media/lechuga.png";
            boton.Content = producto.Nombre;                
            boton.Template = template;                   
            Grid.SetColumn(boton, column);
            Grid.SetRow(boton, row);              
            gridMenu.Children.Add(boton);
            column++;
        } 

    }
```

I tested without margin in the grid and it does not work either

Answer (score 0):

It's because you bind Ellipse Width to the ActualHeight, and since your window isn't square (but wide rectangle), height value is bigger than width, so is not enough wide place to fit square.

To fix that you can remove Ellipse With binding

```
  <Ellipse x:Name="outerCircle"  Fill="Black"/>
  <Ellipse x:Name="inCircle" Margin="5">
       <Ellipse.Fill>
           <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
       </Ellipse.Fill>
  </Ellipse>
```

If you need square, you can use Viewbox, set some height and width on container grid

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="botonProducto" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Grid Margin="20">
            <Viewbox>
                <Grid MinHeight="50" MinWidth="50">
                    <Ellipse x:Name="outerCircle"  Fill="Black"/>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="inCircle" Margin="5">
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
                </Grid>
            </Viewbox>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX=".9" ScaleY=".9"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value=".5,.5"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```